# How to hide focus objects in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I always wondered, is it possible to hide an object focus mark when it got selected?

For example, if you draw a new rectangle its border gets bold and focus and it will remain like this until you deselect it. I find this disturbing and wish to disable this option.

I'm using Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Why do you rating me down? whats wrong with my question?! I did search the web and this forum and didn't find an answer for that. Is this how you welcome new users?!

Comment: you made no mention of what you tried that didn't work and a simple Google search can find tons of results that all say exactly what I did, so you were downvoted because this is basically a RTFM question. http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+turn+off+shape+outline+photoshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will hide it but will also hide any guidelines you have
2. Select the entire layer by clicking on the layer name, not the little box showing the shape. This way you can have your guidelines and not see the shape outline / vector.

Comment: Your first solution works, the second doesn't. Thank you

Comment: @GilPeretz as far as I know both solutions have always worked on hiding the path. In newer versions I think you can even select the layer and as long as you don't have the Pen tool chosen it won't show the vector.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> will "TOGGLE" it and the guidelines too.

Comment: Welcome to GD but I believe the answer above is the exact same thing as this so your answer may be deleted.

Comment: Thanks Matt. he said it will hide it. i corrected it to toggle ;)